# Background Image disappearing in Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css

For some reason, my background images disappear in Microsoft edge when using `background-attachment: fixed`. However works fine in IE, Chrome and Firefox.

css is as followed:

```
header
{
    text-align: center;
    color: #eee;
    background: url(../img/portfolio/66.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 70% 0%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Any ideas?

Regards,

Steve

Comment: seems like a known issue https://teamtreehouse.com/community/background-attachment-is-messed-up-in-ie-and-microsoft-edge  https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/2010901/edge-fixed-elements-backgrounds-are-jumpy-when-scrolling-with-mouse-wheel  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/105741/

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue on my new parallax project, i am not sure is it because i set my div background-attachment: fixed; or overflow:hidden.

But when I tried to move my background css to innner div like below, my problem solved.

```
<div class"header"><div class="bg"></div></div>
```