# Background image not getting display in IE - edge

Tags: html, css

I'm using React: ^15.4.2

**What I did:**

```
<body class="login-background-image">
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.login-background-image {
  background-image: url("/static/media/login-background.62bcd470.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

In chrome: background image getting display properly. But in IE-edge I'm getting **error in console:** DOM7000: Resource 'blob:/static/media/login-background.62bcd470.jpg' not found.

I'm having doubt, is this is a issue because I missed something in my webpack.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41088887/background-image-disappearing-in-microsoft-edge Look at the comments for this question

Comment: But I'm getting following error in console

DOM7000: Resource 'blob:/static/media/login-background.62bcd470.jpg' not found.

And I'm not using any blob image.

Answer (score 0):

```html
.login-background-image {
  background-image: url("static/media/login-background.62bcd470.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer is not giving any hint. Please write some description.